# JavaFX : FXML items are null

Tags: java, javafx, rmi, fxml, fxmlloader

When I try to update my JavaFX app when the server adds a client, I receive a nullpointer for my FXML listview when I use my update function. Any clue why it will work in my intitialise and my events but not in my update method

FXMLController

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable, Remote, ClientObserver {


    @FXML private ListView listview;    

    List<RMIClient> clients;
    RMIServer server;

    public FXMLController(RMIServer server) throws RemoteException
    {
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        if(server != null) {
            try {
            ObservableList<RMIClient> clients = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            clients.addAll(server.getClients());
            if(listview.getItems() == null)
                this.listview.setItems(clients);
            else
                this.listview.getItems().setAll(clients);
            } catch (RemoteException ex) { }
        }
    }    

    @Override
    public void update() {
       System.out.println(listview);
    }

}
```

My Mainapp

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    public static RMIServer server;
    private FXMLController controller;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));
        controller = new FXMLController(server);
        loader.setController(controller);
        server.setObserver(controller);
        Parent root = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

        stage.setTitle("RMINetwork Centre");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * The main() method is ignored in correctly deployed JavaFX application.
     * main() serves only as fallback in case the application can not be
     * launched through deployment artifacts, e.g., in IDEs with limited FX
     * support. NetBeans ignores main().
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         try 
         {
            server = (RMIServer) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/" + RMIServer.class.getTypeName());

         } 
         catch(Exception e) { } 
         launch(args);
    }

}
```

Scene.fxml

```
<BorderPane prefHeight="350" prefWidth="500" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
   <left>
    <ListView fx:id="listview" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="152.0" onMouseClicked="#ChangeContext" />
</left>
</BorderPane>
```

Server class :

```
public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements RMIServer {

    private List<RMIClient> clients;
    private ClientObserver observer;


    public Server() throws RemoteException 
    {
        this.clients = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerClient(RMIClient client) throws RemoteException 
    {
        this.clients.add(client);
        if(observer != null) 
        {  
            this.observer.update(); 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeClient(RMIClient client) throws RemoteException 
    {
        this.clients.remove(client);
        if(observer != null) 
        { 
            this.observer.update(); 
        }
    }

        @Override
public String notifyClient(int index, RMICommand cmd) throws RemoteException 
{
    return this.clients.get(index).executeCommand(cmd);
}

@Override
public List<RMIClient> getClients() throws RemoteException
{
    return this.clients;
}

@Override
public void setObserver(ClientObserver observer) throws RemoteException {
    this.observer = observer;
}
```

So has anyone a clue to solve my problem?

Kind Regards

Comment: How are you adding the ListView in the fxml? Does it has a `fx:id` ?

Comment: yes, it has an id, fx:id="listview"

Comment: Where do you call the `update` method?

Comment: Before or after `FXMLLoader.load` is finished?

Comment: after the FXMLLoader.load

Comment: Where does the `server.setObserver` method come from? [`javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/management/remote/rmi/RMIServer.html) doesn't have one.

Comment: Most likely `observer.update` is called before `FXMLLoader.load()` finishes (`registerClient` or `removeClient` called from diffenent Thread?)

Comment: and how can it be solve?

Comment: Swap lines `server.setObserver(controller); Parent root = loader.load();` or call `setObserver` from `initialize` i.e. make sure the loader has injected the fields before they are used.